# How to evaluate OpenRefine Transform output on many columns cells?

Tags: debian, openrefine

I do the following in [OpenRefine's](http://openrefine.org) Edit Cells on Columns > Transform function but it gives literally from `1h10` to `1*60+10` without evaluting the value by the language *General Refine Expression Language (GREL)*, where other language options are Python and Cjosure

```
replace(value,"h", "*60+")
```

Expected output: `70`

Other examples of data

- `2h08`

### Attempt to affect many columns cells

```
return eval(value.replace("h", "*60+")); # works on the current column

eval(cells("Other_column").value.replace("h", "*60+")) # does not work on other columns
```

Output: unsuccessful

OS: Debian 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python solution on a single column with some data formats of `h0`.

```
import re
value = re.sub("h0", "h",value)
value = re.sub("h","*60+", value)
return eval(value) 
return eval(value.replace("h", "*60+"));
```

Output as expected on a single column.

Next step on many columns: just physically apply on each column. 
If in need, just take the json from extract for other applications.